# Нет доступа из php-webdriver к приложению в docker

Tags: php, docker, selenoid

Есть ubuntu server 20.04. В docker контейнере lamp запущено приложение, порт проброшен и доступ через браузер есть к приложению как `localhost:8000/`. Запущен *selenoid*, которому через *php-webdriver* указываю ссылку `localhost:8000` и пытаюсь установить соединение. Проблема в том, что *php-webdriver* устанавливает соединение с localhost или сайтами в интернете, но к `localhost:8000` не подключается со следующей ошибкой `Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session`

UPD: попробовал запустить тесты без *Selenoid*, то есть указал путь к *webdriverchrome* и `get('localhost:8000')` сработало.
То есть проблема заключается во взаимодействии *Selenoid* и *docker* контейнеров. Как её решить?

Comment: Где запущен selenoid? На хосте или в докере?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Selenoid запущен на ubuntu server в docker контейнере с проброшенным портом 4444
То есть я web-driver нацеливаю на localhost:4444/wd/hub
А приложение тестируемое тоже находится в докере с  проброшенным портом  8000
В итоге получается, что к localhost подключается корректно, а к localhost:8000 не работает.

Comment: и по ссылке ещё парочка дубликатов

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо Вам большое! Помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы.
Решением было указание ip-адреса контейнера. То есть:
было - `get('host-ip:8000')`
стало - `get('container-ip')`
Также пришлось запускать *Selenoid* в той же сети, что и контейнер с *web-приложением*